# FileReader; select file extension

Tags: java, swing, filefilter

I just made a file reader in Java. I will use it for the game Hangman, now the user can chose which word-list/dictionary they want to use.

It works great, but when the user has to select a file, he can chose all types of files. However, I want them to only open `.txt` files to assure the working of the program. What code do I have to use so that the user can only open text files?

This is the file reader method I use:

```
private static ArrayList readData(File someFile)
{
    String data;
    ArrayList<String> aStringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try     // men is verplicht een try block te gebruiken.
         {
             FileReader filereader = new FileReader(someFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gekozen woordenlijst is: " 
                                            + someFile.getAbsolutePath());
             BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);

             while((data = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null)
             {
                 System.out.println("\nIngelezen data is "    + data); 
                 aStringArrayList.add(data);
             }
             filereader.close(); 
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Got an FileNotFoundException: " 
                                               + e.getMessage());
         }  
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Got an IOException: " 
                                               + e.getMessage());
         }
    return (aStringArrayList);
}
```

Comment: FilenameExtensionFilter: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html

Comment: @ControlAltDel  I have to say - if that comment of yours is not the answer, then I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a JFileChooser with a FileNameExtensionFilter.

Something like this:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("txt files", "txt");

chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   // do your stuff here
}
```

parent here being your JFrame.